what can i do to resolve the error shown by command make for genomemapper?
I am trying to download GenomeMapper-0.4.4 from http://1001genomes.org/downloads/genomemapper.html  in my system-gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0.
this is the command i am following as mentioned in the mannual:
tar -zxf genomemapper.tar.gz
cd genomemapper
make (error is showing for this command)
gcc   -Wall -O2 -DMAP_LOAD_GENOME -o genomemapper obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o obj/std/genomemapper/alloc.o obj/std/genomemapper/astr.o obj/std/genomemapper/genomemapper.o obj/std/genomemapper/hit.o obj/std/genomemapper/hitcuda.o obj/std/genomemapper/hitseriell.o obj/std/genomemapper/hitthread.o obj/std/genomemapper/index.o obj/std/genomemapper/init.o obj/std/genomemapper/load.o obj/std/genomemapper/print.o obj/std/genomemapper/read.o obj/std/genomemapper/usage.o
/usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of NUM_MAPPING_ENTRIES'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of MAX_USED_SLOTS'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of CHROMOSOME_ENTRY_OPERATOR'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of HIT_OPERATOR'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x18): multiple definition of HIT_OPERATOR_FIRST'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x18): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x20): multiple definition of MAPPING_ENTRY_OPERATOR'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x20): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x28): multiple definition of MAPPING_ENTRY_OPERATOR_FIRST'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x28): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x30): multiple definition of CHROM_CONTAINER_SIZE'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x30): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x34): multiple definition of LONGEST_CHROMOSOME'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x34): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x38): multiple definition of GENOME'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x38): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x40): multiple definition of HITS_IN_SCORE_LIST'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x40): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x48): multiple definition of HITS_BY_SCORE'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x48): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x50): multiple definition of READSTART_BINS'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x50): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x58): multiple definition of HIT_LISTS_OPERATOR'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x58): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x60): multiple definition of NUM_SCORE_INTERVALS'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x60): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x68): multiple definition of CHR_DESC_TMP'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x68): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x70): multiple definition of CHR_DESC'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x70): first defined here /usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x78): multiple definition of CHR_LENGTH'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x78): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: obj/std/genomemapper/alignthread.o:(.bss+0x80): multiple definition of `CHR_SEQ'; obj/std/genomemapper/alignseriell.o:(.bss+0x80): first defined here

Please edit your question to add correct code block formatting to blocks of code.  You are missing the important error messages from your question.  The last line "Error 1" is just make telling you that the linker command it invoked gcc -Wall ... exited with a non-0 error code (in POSIX 0 is success).  You have to look at the errors that were printed by your linker (which you didn't include here) to know what the problem is.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i don't see any warnings anywhere else with make command. i see the error just at the end as "Error 1".
